# does anyone know how to retrain Object Detection (coco-ssd) of TFJS for object 91?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

So far I seen so many discussion on this topic and using different approaches to achieve this (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1809) but I want to know if anyone managed to successfully use Tensorflowjs to achieve this. 
I know some also achieved this using transfer learning but it is not same as being able to add my own new class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: No, not yet, though technically possible, I have not seen an implementation of this in the wild.

The longer answer - why:

Given that "transfer learning" essentially means reusing the existing knowledge in a trained model to help you then classify things of a similar nature without having to redo all the prior learning there are actually 2 ways to do that:

1) This is the easier route but may not be possible for some use cases: Use one of the high level layers of the frozen model that you have access to (eg the models that are released by TF.js are frozen models I believe - the ones on GitHub). This allows you to reuse some of its lower layers (or final output) which may already be good at picking out certain features that are useful for the use case you need eg object detection in a general sense, which you can then feed into your own unfrozen layers that sit on top of that output you are sampling from (which is where the new training would happen). This is faster as you are only updating weights etc for the new layers you have added, however because the original model is frozen, it means you would have to replicate in TF.js the layers you were bypassing to ensure you have the same resulting model architecture for COCO-SSD in this case if you wanted the architecture. This may not be trivial to do.

2) Retraining the original model - can think of tuning the original model - but this is only possible if you have access to the original unfrozen model and the data used to train that. This would take longer as you are essentially retraining the whole model on all the data + your new data. If you do not have the original unfrozen model, then the only way to do this would be to implement the said model in TF.js yourself using the layers / ops APIs as needed and then use that to train on your own data.

What?!

So an easier to visualize example of this is if we consider PoseNet - the one that estimates where human joints/skeletons are.

Now in this Posenet example imagine you wanted to make a new ML model that could detect when a person is in a certain position - eg waving a hand.

In this example you could use method 1 to simply take the output of existing posenet predictions for all the joints it has detected and feed that into a new layer - something simple like a multi layered perceptron - that could then very quickly learn from example data when a hand was in a waving position for example. In this case we are simply adding to the existing architecture to achieve a new result - gesture prediction vs the raw x-y point predictions for the joints themselves.

Now consider case 2 for PoseNet - you want to be able to recognise a new part of the body that it currently does not. For that to happen you would need to retrain the original model so that it could learn to predict that new body part as part of its output.

This is much harder as you would need to retrain the base model to do this, which means you need to have access to the unfrozen model to do that. If you didn't have access to the unfrozen model then you would have no choice but attempt to recreate PoseNet architecture entirely yourself and then train that with your own data. As you can see this 2nd use case is much harder and more involved to do.

Comment: Many thanks Jason , this is the exact answer I was looking for. I could not get any more accurate answer than the one from the man who is directly involved in tensorflow js. 
So I guess my best bet is to use the transfer learning. Then let’s say I will add some new layers to train the model for two new classes of spoon and Fork. Then how can I identify both spoon and fork in the picture. Do you know any good example of such implementation?

Comment: Using MobileNet (not coco-ssd) you could follow this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html 

I do not believe we have any tutorial to do this with COCO-SSD yet due to the reasons explained above + also we are quite new team so still working on producing more content :-)

COCO-SSD is more complex here because if you sample a lower layer, then all the extra processing that happens above needs to be recreated too -eg the math that calculates bounding boxes etc would need to be re-implemented I believe and that is not  simple